# How do I reserve bandwidth?

Tags: internet, instant-messaging

In windows there is a registry entry called **Reserve bandwidth**. With that system was reserved some bandwidth from my INTERNET connection so that when i am downloading all other connected application can run with minimum INTERNET support.

Like reserve bandwidth help to keep other application (all kind of messenger) **on-line** when i was downloading. But in Ubuntu my connection speed is good enough but problem arise when i am downloading a file, all my messenger gets **off-line status**. Can any one tell how can i fix such problem? Or why this is happening?

Comment: see this answer: http://superuser.com/a/66575/33303

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[(Credit goes to the answerer of this post in Super User)](https://superuser.com/a/66575/134448)

- Install trickle with this command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install trickle
  ```

  Or using Software Center:

  [image: Install via the software center]
- Start any program with trickle specifying it's download limits. For example, opening a new Firefox instance with 20 KB/s download limit, use this command

  ```
  trickle -s -d 20 firefox
  ```

  Here, `-s` saying trickle is running in standalone without any daemon, `-d` is doing the limit on download speed. You can also use `-u` option to specify an upload speed.

[See the trickle manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/trickle.1.html) for more help.

---

#### If you want to limit the bandwidth of the interface card

There is also another tool which can be used to limit the speed of a Network interface. It's called wondershaper. With this tool you can limit the speed of the interface card.

- Install it with this command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wondershaper
  ```

  Or using Software Center:

  [image: Install via the software center]
- To limit the download speed of eth1 interface to 2000 Kilobit/sec, I'd run this command:

  `wondershaper eth1 2000`

  The exact syntax is

  `wondershaper [ interface ] [ downlink ] [ uplink ]`

[Manual page for wondershaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/wondershaper.8.html)

Comment: Can I ask the downvoter the reason of their downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

Try pyshaper: http://freecode.com/projects/pyshaper

Let me know if it is useful.

Also checkout `iftop` via software-center for a visualiation of what is going on with your network.

Comment: Seems to be dead